# NLP for java, which toolkit should I use?

Tags: java, text, nlp, text-mining

I'm working on a project that needs to count the occurrence of every word of a txt file.
For example, I have a text file like this:

> What Silver Lake Looks For in IPO Candidates
>   3 Companies Crushed by Earnings: Apple, Cirrus Logic, IBM
>   IBM's Palmisano: How You Get To Be A 100-Year Old Company

If there are 3 sentences shown above in the file and I want to calculate every word's occurrence. Here, Companies and company should be considered as the same word "company"(lowercase), so the total occurrence for the word "company" is 2.

Is there any NLP toolkit for java that can tell two words like "families" and "family" are actually from the same word "family"?

I'll count the occurrence of every word to further do the Naive Bayes training, so it's very important to get the accurate numbers of occurrences of each word.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/tomwhite/archive/2006/07/pluralization.html

Comment: Some useful terminology: a tool that tells you that families and family belong to the same *lexeme* is called a *stemmer*. Word counts are also called unigram frequencies. A model that treats a document as a feature vector of word counts is called *bag-of-words*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) provide good stemming algorithm implementations. You can review and use the best one that suites you. I've been using Lucene for my projects.

Comment: Actually what I'm going to do is something called lemmatization, which works better in my project. Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful resource for java implementation. The only one I found out is the StanfordNLP java library, but it seems not working functionally. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can check LingPipe too : http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at GATE : http://gate.ac.uk/

If you want to use words to train a bag-of-word model, you can use TF-IDF value instead of the absolute count.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: It reminds me of the model in database computing the word's weight among the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is called stemming (getting the root word).

As mentioned, Lingpipe, Gate and Lucene/Solr do stemming. Another option is the stanford parser. Or you could implement the Porter Stemming algo yourself.